# How to set armature default settings, so that X-Ray is checked when an armature is created?

Tags: armature

I always want X-Ray to be checked when I create armatures. Is there a way to set this as default?

Comment: Don't know if this works for X-Ray, but for many properties the solution is to start from a new blend file, set the option the way you want it, make sure everything else is the same as when you started, and then save the startup file.  (File -> Save Startup File) or CTRL-U

Comment: @MartyFouts Thanks. I added an armature and ticked X-Ray, then Ctrl+U to save. After this, when I create a new file, an armature is pre-created with X-Ray ticked. But when I create another armature in this file, X-Ray is still unticked.